# Top N records in SQL Server with parameter shows error

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I'm writing a stored procedure to return N records based on input parameter passing:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[StaffQueue]
    @Staff_Dept VARCHAR(100),
    @numberOfStaffs INT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(1000)

    SET @SQL = 'select top ('+ @numberOfStaffs +') Display_Name as 
   StaffName,e.Emp_code as StaffCode from Employee e'

    IF @Staff_Dept > ''
       SET @SQL = @SQL + ' where e.Designation IN ('''+@Staff_Dept+''')';

    EXEC(@SQL);
END
```

When I execute this stored procedure like this:

```
EXEC StaffQueue @Staff_Dept ='', @numberOfStaffs = 10
```

it shows an error:

> Conversion error near Top('

Can anyone help me solve this error?

Comment: Try to print @SQL first and check

Comment: @RedDevil.. can u show how to print it friend?

Comment: Comment EXEC (@SQL) and write print @sql

Answer (score 2):

You need to either change the datatype of @numberOfStaffs to varchar or convert it in the query

```
SET @SQL= 'select top ('+ CONVERT(varchar(10), @numberOfStaffs) +') Display_Name as 
   StaffName,e.Emp_code as StaffCode from Employee e'

  IF @Staff_Dept>''
     SET @SQL = @SQL + ' where e.Designation IN ('''+@Staff_Dept+''')';
```

Answer (score 0):

You should cast your `@numberOfStaffs` to `varchar` before concatenating to the dynamic sql string.

```
SET @SQL= 'select top ('+ cast(@numberOfStaffs as varchar(max)) +') Display_Name as 
   StaffName,e.Emp_code as StaffCode from Employee e'
```

Answer (score 0):

You just did a SQL syntax error by using parenthesis for the **TOP** instruction.

```
Select Top(5) * From Mytable -- this is wrong
Select Top 5  * From Mytable -- this is good
```

Comment: Not only are the parentheses allowed, but they are actually mandated by the syntax diagram (check at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#syntax): " [TOP ( expression ) [PERCENT] [ WITH TIES ] ]".  That they are optional surprises me.  Microsoft should fix the bug in the documentation.

Comment: @GordonLinoff,  they are not allowed in SQL Server 2005 though